Least non-zero singular value for a singular matrix
I understand that the least singular value is the result of the following minimization:
$$\sigma_{min} = \min_{||x||=1} ||Ax||$$
When the matrix $A$ loses rank, the $\sigma_{min}$ become $0$. Is the least non-zero singular value equal to the following minimization?
$$\sigma_{min} = \min_{||x||=1} ||Ax|| $$
$$  \textrm{s.t.} \quad x \in Null(A)^{\perp}$$
In text: if matrix $A$ loses rank, and thus has a null space, is the least non-zero singular corresponding to the least stretching factor to the vectors that are in the orthogonal complement of the null space of $A$? If so, how can I show this property?
Thank you!

The proof is straightforward from writing $\|Ax\|^2$ in terms of the SVD $A = UDV^T$. We have $Ax = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}\sigma_{j}(x, v_j)u_j$, so $\|Ax\|^2 = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}\sigma_{j}^2|(x, v_j)|^2 = \sum_{j = \ell}^{n}\sigma_{j}^2|(x, v_j)|^2$, where $\ell$ is the index of the first nonzero singular value. The proof is immediate from here.

Thank you so much, @Kakashi! Looks like there is one more constraint $\sum_{j=l}^{n} | (x,v_j)|^2=1$ that needs to be satisfied for the proof to get the result, right?

Responding to myself, it's always true that $\sum_{j=1}^{n} |(x, v_j)|^2 = 1$ for $||x||=1$ and $v_1, ..., v_j$ are the orthonormal basis for the space that $x$ is in.

Since $v_1, \dots, v_n$ are an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, for any vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, you can check that $$y = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}(y, v_j)v_j$$ and therefore by the pythagorean theorem, $|y|^2 =  \sum_{j = 1}^{n}|(y, v_j)|^2$.

Yes, that's true. One way to see this is to think of the nullspace as being spanned by the right singular vectors whose singular value is $0$. Since the right singular vectors are orthogonal, the orthogonal complement of the nullspace is spanned by the right singular vectors whose singular value is nonzero.
This can also be seen as a special case of the variational characterization of the singular values.

Thank you so much, @Qiaochu Yuan! Are the right singular vectors a set of orthonormal bases for the space of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

@William: yes. You can probably consult any text that develops the SVD but I happen to like the way I did it here: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2017/03/13/singular-value-decomposition/
